# C# subtract time (hours minutes)

Tags: c#, datetime

Hello Everyone I have some interesting situation.

I want to count how many hours (in minutes) is from 20:00 to 01:00 AM, but i Don't know how, because what i have done is:

```
pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = 01:00;
pradziosLaikoLaukelis = 20:00;
TimeSpan dt = Convert.ToDateTime(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis)- Convert.ToDateTime(pradziosLaikoLaukelis);
int minutes = (int)dt.TotalMinutes;
```

And i get result -> -1140 minutes, but I need that answer to be just 5 hours from 20:00 to 01:00.

I know that it is quite easy, but i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You are crossing a date boundary (1AM today - 8PM today). If you do not supply that information, C# is never going to know about it.

Comment: The result is correct. You need to ensure that the time from tomorrow is actually in the correct date. Try adding one day to the result of first Convert.ToDateTime.

Comment: And use `TotalHours` instead of `TotalMinutes`

Comment: I don't know if this is only for the question. You should create `TimeSpans` using e.g. `TimeSpan.FromHours(hours)` or from one of its constructors. Don't use strings.

Comment: 20 to 01 AM is not how its expressed AM/PM is a 12/12 hour time system while 20 belongs to the 24hour time system

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
        //Datetime(Year,month,day,hour,min,sec)
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0);
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0);
        string minutes = (date2.Subtract(date1).TotalMinutes).ToString();
```

Tested and works 300 minutes (5 hours)

Comment: You can use with TimeStamp to subtract hour and minute if you want

Comment: The question is to subtract and get the period in minutes between two DateTimes. Not to subtract a period og e.g. Minutes from a DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

Use full date time strings that contain day part, to show that 01:00 AM is one day later than 20:00 - like following:

```
int minutes = Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/2012 01:00").Substract(Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2012 20:00")).TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Day, you are subracting (Today 1:00 AM) - (Today 8:00 PM)

I think you need to subract (Tommorrow 1:00 AM) - (Today 8:00 PM)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a day to the first `TimeSpan` and use `TotalHours`.

```
var pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = "01:00";
var pradziosLaikoLaukelis = "20:00";
var oneDayTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan dt = TimeSpan.Parse(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis).Add(oneDayTimeSpan) - TimeSpan.Parse(pradziosLaikoLaukelis);
int minutes = (int)dt.TotalHours; // 5 hours
```

Using associative operations:

```
var pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = "21:00";
var pradziosLaikoLaukelis = "20:00";
var leftHours = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis).TotalHours;
var rightHours = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(pradziosLaikoLaukelis).TotalHours;
// Now we do a Modulus operation which will assure
// 23 > hours > 0
// Make sure to check that leftHours != 0 or rightHours != 0
int hours = (Math.Abs(leftHours * rightHours) + leftHours) % rightHours; //Modulus
var hoursTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
```

Comment: If the endtime is 21:00, this will give him 25 hours instead of 1.

Comment: Well yes because time operations are not associative. It would be better to just use math at that point.

Comment: @caerolus I provided an example.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with adding one day to the endTime, because then the difference between 20:00 and 22:00 will be 26 hours instead of 2!

Just check whether the difference is positive (same day) or negative (next day)

```
string pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = "01:00";
string pradziosLaikoLaukelis = "20:00";
// This should be 5 hours
TimeSpan dt = Convert.ToDateTime(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis) - Convert.ToDateTime(pradziosLaikoLaukelis);
int hours = (int)dt.TotalHours;
hours = hours < 0 ? 24 + hours : hours;
// This should be 19 hours
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(pradziosLaikoLaukelis) - Convert.ToDateTime(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis);
hours = (int)dt.TotalHours;
hours = hours < 0 ? 24 + hours : hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of preparation of the two string variables is required before attempting data calculations

```
string pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = "01:00";
string pradziosLaikoLaukelis = "20:00";
pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + pabaigosLaikoLaukelis;
pradziosLaikoLaukelis = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + pradziosLaikoLaukelis;

TimeSpan dt = Convert.ToDateTime(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis) - Convert.ToDateTime(pradziosLaikoLaukelis);
Console.WriteLine("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", dt.Hours, dt.Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
pabaigosLaikoLaukelis = 01:00;
pradziosLaikoLaukelis = 20:00;
TimeSpan startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(pradziosLaikoLaukelis).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(pabaigosLaikoLaukelis).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan diff = endTime > startTime ? endTime - startTime : endTime - startTime + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
int minutes = (int)diff.TotalMinutes;
```